# Django Pytest. Use database entries in parametrize

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I want to have a test for data that will use real data from DB.

The goal is to go through all the entries of a table `Foo` and apply some test logic on each entry. Ideally is to use `parametrize` for that but I am a bit struggling with DB access to `parametrize`.

What I do so far:

**tests.py**

```
import pytest
from app.models import Foo

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestFoo:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('foo', Foo.objects.all())
    def test_foo_objects(self, foo):
        assert foo.is_ok
```

Eventually I get

> E   RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.

However, if DB-access is not used in `parametrize` - it works. I.e inside `test_foo_objects` DB-access is allowed.

So the question is how to allow `parametrize` use DB as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no **simple** way to do that, because:

> The parametrization of test functions happens ***at collection time***.  (according to [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources)).

Even if you would like to use `pytest_generate_tests` function you need to get your `Foo` model (data) **without using any fixture** (provided by `pytest-django` plugin).

I tried Django's [deserializing data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data) way from pre-saved model in JSON file, generated by `dumpdata` CLI command. But no success for me :(.
Direct connection to the database remains a final way to retrieve data for model. But it's too complicated for such task, I think. It's better to extract model (table) into plain text file and parse it for parametrization [arguments](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.Metafunc.parametrize). If you really need to.

Comment: thanks for your answer. At the end of the day - I just created script (regular Django command) to make this report i.o. using pytest